# Inserting a record where corresponding record does not exist

Tags: sql, oracle

I have TBLISSUES containing the following data :-

```
ISSUEID QUOTEID ISSUE_TYPE  DATE_ADDED  DATE_RESOLVED   RESOLVED_BY RESOLVED
4312    989435  TPIUplift   14-Jun-18                               N
4316    989077  TPIUplift   14-Jun-18                               N
4333    989071  TPIUplift   14-Jun-18                               N
4324    988403  TPIUplift   14-Jun-18   14-Jun-18       JohnSmith   Y
4323    988402  TPIUplift   14-Jun-18                               N
4317    987964  TPIUplift   14-Jun-18                               N
```

and this script :-

```
INSERT INTO tblissues (
    quoteid,
    issue_type,
    date_added,
    resolved
)
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                q.quoteid,
                'TPIUplift',
                trunc(SYSDATE) newissuedate,
                'N'
            FROM
                tblquotesnew q
                LEFT JOIN tbltariffsnew t ON q.tariff_id = t.tariffid
            WHERE
                t.uplift = 0
                AND   q.sales_route = 'TPI'
                AND   q.quote_status = 'Accepted'
                AND   q.status <> 'Cancelled'
        ) x
```

The script looks for issues (which will always exist). I want a new record to be added, only if an existing resolved record does not exist.

I have tried using this in the where clause of the insert, but a row is still added

```
  WHERE
        NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                tblissues
            WHERE
                (x.quoteid = tblissues.quoteid
                AND   tblissues.issue_type = 'TPIUplift'
                AND   tblissues.resolved <> 'Y')
```

So using the sample data above, I would not want a row inserted for QUOTEID 988403, as it's RESOLVED value is Y.

Is this possible?

Comment: I think you need to do `tblissues.resolved = 'Y'` instead of `tblissues.resolved <> 'Y'` on the last line of your `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: @EzLo If I do that it adds a record for every existing record that is resolved <> 'Y'

Comment: You have a `NOT EXISTS` preceding that query, so it will only insert the new values if a record with `resolved = 'Y'` **isn't** already on that table, which is what you need.

Comment: @EzLo It's not behaving in that way.  Again, it's inserting records for all existing records where resolved <> 'Y'.

Comment: What's your primary key?

Comment: @KaushikNayak ISSUEID

Comment: Show us what exactly you want to see after running the insert, for all those rows, and try to include more than one quoteid sample. Also tell us , how many rows does the  select return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would not want a row inserted for QUOTEID 988403, as it's RESOLVED
>   value is Y.

Considering this and the fact that your `QUOTEID` is different, but `ISSUE_TYPE` same for all records , Shouldn't you be simply using this?

```
  WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  ..
  ..
        (
          WHERE   tblissues.ISSUE_TYPE = x.ISSUE_TYPE
           AND    tblissues.resolved   = 'Y' )
```

If not, please update your question and add some more rows for the expected output and clearly explain what you want.